# Symfony2 Form Embed deep relationship in Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity-relationship, symfony-forms

In my Entity Models I have a `User` which is connected through `Enrollment` in an `Organization`.

`User` has a **one to one relationship** with `Enrollment` and `Enrollment` has a **many to one relationship** with `Organization`

`Enrollment` has an attribute *approved*

When the user registers I'd like to have a *list of of Organization names in a dropdown choice list*.
If the `User` registers an `Enrollment` object is created which connects the `User` with an `Organization`.

Since there is no direct link between `User` and `Organization` it seems impossible to get it in the Symfony2 Form.

Any ideas on how to embed deep relationships in a form? If there's a direct link I usually just use the form builder and add an entity but now there isn't a direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be sure, that a user has everytime an enrollment you could do something like this:

```
$builder->add('organizations', 'entity', array('property_path' => 'enrollment.organizations', ));
```

or an other solution could be, if you define a querybuilder

```
$builder->add('organisations', 'entity', array(
            'class' => '%ENTITY_NAME%',
            'query_builder' => function (%REPOSITORY_NAME% $repository) {
                return %QUERY%;
            }
        ));
```

or use an event listener

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($factory) {
    $data = $event->getData();                     
    if ($data->getEnrollment()) {
        $organisations = $data->getEnrollment()->getOrganisations();
    } else {
        $organisations = ...
    }
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $form->add($factory->createNamed('organizations', 'entity', $organisations, array('required' => false)));
});
```